# HTC Vive as second Monitor

Tags: monitor, htc-vive

Heyho,

now, I know that similar questions have been asked throughout the internet but the answers were always the same "don´t do it because the resolution is bad". For the project I am working on the quality is not so important. I just need to know if and how it is possible to use the Vive as a simple (second) monitor. I want to simply see my for example browser window just like I am seeing it on a normal monitor. Stuff like Bigscreen VR or Virtual Desktop aren´t what I am looking for.

Thanks in advance for the answers.

Answer (score 0):

Which operating system? If it is on Linux and X11:

The `nvidia` driver has the option

```
Option "AllowHMD" "yes/no"
```

that if set to `yes` will present the HMD as a regular display device.

Comment: I am using Windows 10. Is there a similar way of doing this?

Comment: I would prefer to solve it without, but if there is no other way I take the chance :)

Comment: @TheNicojack: Essentially what happens is, that the GPU's drivers (and later even firmware, after an update) take the HMDs EDID data as a hint, to treat it as a special device. If the specific HMD identifier is stripped from the EDID data, it'll be treated as a regular display. Inserting a EDID Emulator (Google it) will do the trick, as long as it "overwrites" the Display vendor and product information.